# Fatal error when getting the results using jQuery and Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to reload the fresh posts using jQuery. As far as I know, I can't reload the contents of a div inside the page so I reload a file into that div. (Is that correct?)

The problem is that my loaded file gives me a **Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_head()**

How can I implement functions to a newly created file inside the theme directory to work properly?

***This is my jQuery***

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
    var SANAjax = function(){
        $('#reservationdetails').empty().addClass('loading')
          .load('wp-content/themes/theme/reloadhomeposts.php', function() {
             $(this).removeClass('loading') 
          });
    }
    setInterval(SANAjax, 15000 );
});
</script>
<div id="reservationdetails"></div>
```

***And this is what i have in reloadhomeposts.php (I have deleted the content though)***

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=3,4,5&showposts=10"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
.
.
.
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine (about the WP functionality you are missing) if you add this to your  **reloadhomeposts.php** file before you call any WP function:

```
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
// ... WP_Query call and loop
```

Comment: BTW, if you just want to reload the current page posts via AJAX, why not calling the current url and extract the content of the div you want to "refresh" ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting that error because you are calling the theme file directly

OR

because you aren't incuding the header and footer of the page.

Easy Solve:

Make sure the page loads as wanted. If you dont want to include the header and all that junk, you can load a fragment with jQuery doing something like this:

```
  .load('wp-content/themes/theme/reloadhomeposts.php #postWrapper', function() {
             $(this).removeClass('loading') 
    });
```

Comment: How can I add those functions into the file ?

Comment: Which functions? You should make sure your file loads properly without JS first

Comment: It does by using include(myfile)

Comment: Then you should be off to the races. The error you are getting is a PHP compile error and has nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX can call /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php , with an action parameter (and whatever you want), then in a plugin file you can associate your ajax call to  :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_YOUR_ACTION_NAME', 'the_function_to_call');
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_YOUR_ACTION_NAME', 'the_function_to_call');
```

YOUR_ACTION_NAME must be the value of the action parameter.
The first one, is a public ajax request, means you can call it even if your not logged in
The second one, need that you're logged on.

Then the function the_function_to_call can include whatever, it will works !

```
function the_function_to_call () {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/reloadhomeposts.php');
    die(); // prevent string 1 to appear after
}
```

A little complicated but you are using WP internals process for AJAX.

Comment: Hello there and thanks for your answer. But, which actions or function should i call?

Comment: It's up to you, you have to create an action, for exemple action 'getallpost' , then when you make your ajax call, add this to the url : ?action=getallpost

Comment: And for the fonction, you have to créat it and chosse a proper name for it ! That's all.